# I have a error while running my TestNG in Eclipse IDE , Can anyone have a look

Tags: maven-plugin, rest-assured, testng-eclipse, rest-assured-jsonpath, testng-annotation-test

This is the Code:

```
package myrestassuredpractise;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
public class RestAssuredDemo {
@Test
public void getjsondataTest() {  Response response = RestAssured.get("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=e8bc3d3d57aeb071425da856a8f2ce43");
int code = response.getStatusCode();
Assert.assertEquals(200, code);
System.out.println(response.asString());    
System.out.println(response.getTimeIn(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));  
   }    
}
```

Below is the Error:
[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0yBd.jpg)[pom_xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zKPN.jpg)[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.
FAILED: getMethod
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.isValidWeakMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:284)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassForClass(ClassInfo.java:254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:310)
at io.restassured.authentication.NoAuthScheme.$getStaticMetaClass(NoAuthScheme.groovy)
at io.restassured.authentication.NoAuthScheme.`enter code here`(NoAuthScheme.groovy)`enter code here`
at io.restassured.RestAssured.(RestAssured.java:354)
at myrestassuredpractise.chapter1.getMethod(chapter1.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-xml is loaded in version 3.0.8 and you are trying to load version 3.0.7
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:510)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:87)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:81)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModulesFrom(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:63)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:54)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:86)
at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.(GroovySystem.java:37)
... 32 more

## ===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

## ===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Comment: please show your code and which line of code that produced this error.

Comment: i have attached images of my "Code" & "Pom.xml" files(dependencies) . Pls have a look. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you change the class name? because in the stack trace. code error at `myrestassuredpractise.chapter1.getMethod(chapter1.java:14)`

Comment: No, id did not change the class name. If you have observed closely the error says "groovy" . Is this something related to groovy ?1

Comment: Could you show me the code of class `chapter1.java`. Nothing wrong with groovy because Rest-Assured using groovy internally.

Comment: I have pasted my Code, pls have a look